# Is there a way to see a list of amendments to a proposed directive?

Tags: european-union

I would like to identify how Article 13 of the proposed [Directive on Copyright in the Digital Single Market 2016/0280(COD)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_on_Copyright_in_the_Digital_Single_Market) has changed over time.

Is there a way to see this?

Comment: While I can find a handful of directives with similar names, I can't find one with the exact name to which you're referring.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: Does this mean anything to you? COM/2016/0593 final - 2016/0280 (COD). I am talking about this proposal: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_on_Copyright_in_the_Digital_Single_Market

Comment: As far as I can tell, this directive is still a proposal at this stage, and has not been enacted into law.  Is your question about how it's been amended during the parliamentary process?

Comment: My question was really whether the development process of the proposed directive was conveniently visible, from inception, through amendments. I understand it has passed the Parliament, but it is not in force. I guess that means it is being looked about by the Council of Ministers?

Comment: @Ben It appears to be even more complicated than that https://www.engadget.com/2019/01/19/eu-copyright-directive-rejected-at-council/